# External service mock for method doesn't work

Tags: c#, xunit

We have some external service method to call from our code, looks. like

```
AssignOrderReserveCommandResponseDto response = await _supplyReservesClient.AssignOrderReserve(
    masterReserveId,
    inboundReserveId,
    deliveryDate,
    orderInfos,
    cancellationToken)
```

Mock for this method looks like:

```
public static readonly ISupplyReservesClient SupplyReservesClient = Substitute.For<ISupplyReservesClient>();
public static AssignOrderReserveCommandResponseDto assignOrderReserveCommandResponse;

static SupplyReservesClientMock()
{
    SupplyReservesClient
         .AssignOrderReserve(Arg.Any<Guid>(), Arg.Any<Guid>(),
             Arg.Any<DateTimeOffset>(), Arg.Any<IReadOnlyCollection<AssignOrderInfo>>(),
             Arg.Any<CancellationToken>())
         .Returns(_ => assignOrderReserveCommandResponse);
}

public static void SetAssignOrderReserveCommandResponseDto(long bidId, long otherBidId)
{
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
    assignOrderReserveCommandResponse = fixture.Build<AssignOrderReserveCommandResponseDto>()
        .With(x => x.OrderInfos, new List<AssignOrderReserveCommandResponseDto.OrderInfo>()
        {
            new(bidId, "1", DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(3)),
            new(otherBidId, "1", DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(3))
        })
        .With(x => x.InboundReserveId, fixture.Create<Guid>())
        .Create();
}
```

Mock doesn't work and method returns null when I use debug for my test or just run test

Method for mock:

```
public async Task<AssignOrderReserveCommandResponseDto> AssignOrderReserve(
    Guid? masterReserveId,
    Guid? inboundReserveId,
    DateTimeOffset deliveryDate,
    IReadOnlyCollection<AssignOrderInfo> orderInfos,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    AssignOrderReserveCommand command = AssignOrderReserveConverter
        .Convert(masterReserveId, inboundReserveId, deliveryDate, orderInfos);

    AssignOrderReserveCommandResponse response = await _supplyReservesClient
        .AssignOrderReserveAsync(command, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

    return AssignOrderReserveConverter.Convert(response);
}
```

Comment: `Guid` parameters are nullable, but it's declared in mock no nullable. I vaguely know mock, maybe you need to replace `Arg.Any<Guid>()` by `Arg.Any<Nullable<Guid>>()`?

Comment: You haven't posted all your code.  Where is `SupplyReservesClientMock()` being called?